# How to convert text data into an Image?

Tags: delphi

Once you load and image into a component, I can see that Delphi store the image data on DFM, . Example:

```
object img1: TImage
  Left = 71
  Top = 2
  Width = 18
  Height = 18
  Picture.Data = {
    0954506E67496D61676589504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000000100000
    001008060000001FF3FF610000000473424954080808087C0864880000000970
    485973000000750000007501E3C207650000001974455874536F667477617265
    007777772E696E6B73636170652E6F72679BEE3C1A000000EF4944415478DAAD
    923B0AC2401086B3D7100F6110B415FBD8AB60E323E62262632DF15158A8BDB6
    22D682E821C41B58C76F7003EB8A9A10073E36ECFCFB6766765514458E842258
    3A5083A2F38C136C6016C5422B94EC7336C7F7122A7081A3CE97A0000768A2BD
    BD1968F6E0428068FD2250AACE32863354ED4AE4701726D0B00F5B262BE8A199
    DA065BC893709D2F8189547045E7D906D2D79684FFC32064F1D0E5FE6E90B985
    CC434C738DF2F7BB7995691E521F163A1FC4262AE15396AA7650D6FBD2862F26
    EAC313B767A0741BE64DCD657E890C0C93500F3D8E616203C344CA6FEBAD5B2A
    03C364002D183D00658D8FCCCDEDEA100000000049454E44AE426082}
end
```

As you can see it's an small image. How it's possible to get this information without the DFM and make it an Image, for example:

```
procedure TForm12.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  img2: TImage;
  Loutput: TStream;
begin
  ObjectTextToBinary(TStringStream.Create(
     '0954506E67496D61676589504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000000100000'
    + '001008060000001FF3FF610000000473424954080808087C0864880000000970'
    + '485973000000750000007501E3C207650000001974455874536F667477617265'
    + '007777772E696E6B73636170652E6F72679BEE3C1A000000EF4944415478DAAD'
    + '923B0AC2401086B3D7100F6110B415FBD8AB60E323E62262632DF15158A8BDB6'
    + '22D682E821C41B58C76F7003EB8A9A10073E36ECFCFB6766765514458E842258'
    + '3A5083A2F38C136C6016C5422B94EC7336C7F7122A7081A3CE97A0000768A2BD'
    + 'BD1968F6E0428068FD2250AACE32863354ED4AE4701726D0B00F5B262BE8A199'
    + 'DA065BC893709D2F8189547045E7D906D2D79684FFC32064F1D0E5FE6E90B985'
    + 'CC434C738DF2F7BB7995691E521F163A1FC4262AE15396AA7650D6FBD2862F26'
    + 'EAC313B767A0741BE64DCD657E890C0C93500F3D8E616203C344CA6FEBAD5B2A'
    + '03C364002D183D00658D8FCCCDEDEA100000000049454E44AE426082'), Loutput);
  img2 := TImage.Create(self);
  img2.Name := 'image2';
  img2.Left := 71;
  img2.Top := 30;
  img2.Width := 18;
  img2.Height := 18;
  img2.Picture.Graphic.LoadFromStream(Loutput);

  img1.Parent := Self;
end;
```

Comment: It is base16 encoded, aka hex. There will also be some meta data on the front. Read the source code for TPicture to work out what that meta data is. The rest is easy enough.

Comment: `ObjectTextToBinary()` will not work in this situation, because 1) it is looking for an actual DFM and will fail in this example since it is only a piece of a larger DFM, and 2) even if it did not fail, it writes a DFM signature to the output stream, which would corrupt the image loading if you don't skip it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot access the `TPicture.Graphic` property until an image has been loaded into the `TPicture` first.

`TPicture` does not support loading data from a `TStream` (see [QC #12434: Add LoadFromStream() method to TPicture](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=12434)), so you will have to stream the image data manually.

The `Picture.Data` property data starts with a UTF-8 encoded `ShortString` containing the name of the `TGraphic`-derived class that produced the image data.  In your example, that class name is encoded as:

```
0954506E67496D616765
```

The first byte (hex `09`) is the number of bytes in the class name (9), the following 9 bytes (hex `54 50 6E 67 49 6D 61 67 65`) are the UTF-8 octets of the class name (`TPngImage`), and the remaining stream bytes are the actual PNG image data.

So, you need to:

1. extract the class name from the stream.
2. instantiate the specified `TGraphic`-derived class type.
3. load the remaining stream into the object.
4. assign the object to `TPicture`.

For example:

```pascal
uses
  System.Classes,
  System.SysUtils,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Imaging.Jpeg,
  Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg,
  Vcl.Imaging.PngImage;

type
  TGraphicAccess = class(TGraphic)
  end;

procedure TForm12.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Linput: String;
  Loutput: TMemoryStream;
  LclsName: ShortString;
  Lgraphic: TGraphic;
  img2: TImage;
begin
  Linput := '0954506E67496D61676589504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000000100000'
          + '001008060000001FF3FF610000000473424954080808087C0864880000000970'
          + '485973000000750000007501E3C207650000001974455874536F667477617265'
          + '007777772E696E6B73636170652E6F72679BEE3C1A000000EF4944415478DAAD'
          + '923B0AC2401086B3D7100F6110B415FBD8AB60E323E62262632DF15158A8BDB6'
          + '22D682E821C41B58C76F7003EB8A9A10073E36ECFCFB6766765514458E842258'
          + '3A5083A2F38C136C6016C5422B94EC7336C7F7122A7081A3CE97A0000768A2BD'
          + 'BD1968F6E0428068FD2250AACE32863354ED4AE4701726D0B00F5B262BE8A199'
          + 'DA065BC893709D2F8189547045E7D906D2D79684FFC32064F1D0E5FE6E90B985'
          + 'CC434C738DF2F7BB7995691E521F163A1FC4262AE15396AA7650D6FBD2862F26'
          + 'EAC313B767A0741BE64DCD657E890C0C93500F3D8E616203C344CA6FEBAD5B2A'
          + '03C364002D183D00658D8FCCCDEDEA100000000049454E44AE426082';

  Loutput := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Loutput.Size := Length(Linput) div 2;
    HexToBin(PChar(Linput), Loutput.Memory^, Loutput.Size);

    LclsName := PShortString(Loutput.Memory)^;

    Lgraphic := TGraphicClass(FindClass(UTF8Decode(LclsName))).Create;
    try
      Loutput.Position := 1 + Length(LclsName);
      TGraphicAccess(Lgraphic).ReadData(Loutput);

      img2 := TImage.Create(self);
      img2.Parent := Self;
      img2.Name := 'image2';
      img2.Left := 71;
      img2.Top := 30;
      img2.Width := 18;
      img2.Height := 18;
      img2.Picture.Assign(Lgraphic);
    finally
      Lgraphic.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Loutput.Free;
  end;
end;

initialization
  // this is not necessary for TPicture's own DFM streaming,
  // but it is necessary for manual streaming, unless you
  // implement your own classname lookups...
  // 
  RegisterClass(TMetafile);
  RegisterClass(TIcon);
  RegisterClass(TBitmap);
  RegisterClass(TWICImage);
  RegisterClass(TJpegImage);
  RegisterClass(TGifImage);
  RegisterClass(TPngImage);
  // and so on...
end.
```

Comment: +!, I added a bitmap picture to a TImage, then copied Picture.Data from DFM file and assigned it to LInput as a static string, but an error shown : "The Bitmap image is not valid". the String value is exactly Picture.Data value in DFM

Comment: @G3ntle_Man: My bad.  After creating the `TGraphic` object, the code needs to call `TGraphic.ReadData()` instead of `TGraphic.LoadFromStream()`.  For `TBitmap`, there is an extra value present in the stream data (the BMP byte size) after the class name and before the actual BMP data. `TBitmap` needs to read that value, or you get the "not valid" error. `TPngImage` does not have any extra data, the stream data after the class name is just PNG data, which is why my original code worked fine before. I have fixed the code to account for this now.

Answer (score 3):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  CONST_SIGN = '0954506E67496D616765';
var
  LString: String;
  LStart: Integer;
  LStringStream: TStringStream;
  LMem: TMemoryStream;
  R: TBytes;
begin
  LString :=
    '0954506E67496D61676589504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000000100000'
    + '001008060000001FF3FF610000000473424954080808087C0864880000000970'
    + '485973000000750000007501E3C207650000001974455874536F667477617265'
    + '007777772E696E6B73636170652E6F72679BEE3C1A000000EF4944415478DAAD'
    + '923B0AC2401086B3D7100F6110B415FBD8AB60E323E62262632DF15158A8BDB6'
    + '22D682E821C41B58C76F7003EB8A9A10073E36ECFCFB6766765514458E842258'
    + '3A5083A2F38C136C6016C5422B94EC7336C7F7122A7081A3CE97A0000768A2BD'
    + 'BD1968F6E0428068FD2250AACE32863354ED4AE4701726D0B00F5B262BE8A199'
    + 'DA065BC893709D2F8189547045E7D906D2D79684FFC32064F1D0E5FE6E90B985'
    + 'CC434C738DF2F7BB7995691E521F163A1FC4262AE15396AA7650D6FBD2862F26'
    + 'EAC313B767A0741BE64DCD657E890C0C93500F3D8E616203C344CA6FEBAD5B2A'
    + '03C364002D183D00658D8FCCCDEDEA100000000049454E44AE426082';

  { Find and rid signature }

  LStart := Pos(CONST_SIGN, LString);

  if LStart = 0 then
    Exit;

  Delete(LString, LStart, Length(CONST_SIGN));

  { Main }

  LStringStream := TStringStream.Create(LString);
  LMem := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    { Prepare out array }
    SetLength(R, Length(LString) div SizeOf(Char));

    { Convert }
    HexToBin(PWideChar(LString), R, Length(LString) div SizeOf(Char));

    { Copy array to stream }
    LMem.WriteBuffer(R[0], Length(R));

    { Save stream with image as file }
    LMem.SaveToFile('xxx.png');

    { Load image from file }
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('xxx.png');
  finally
    LStringStream.Free;
    LMem.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it's specific to the data that the OP posted, and not generic for all image components stored in the DFM. You've hard-coded in one specific image.

Comment: @KenWhite yes, i just provided more correct code for his example, which are demonstrate that it's possible to do. about `generic for all image components stored in the DFM` -- that sound like different/next question.

Comment: The question asks about how to *convert text data into an image*, and also says *for example, this text* (which means it's only an example of the *type of text*). Your answer says *for this exact text*.

Comment: @KenWhite can you explain, why code example from Remy Lebeau with also HARDCODED data are better than my code example? Answer from Remy Lebeau also do not answer on your question `generic for all image components stored in the DFM`.

Comment: Because Remy's explains what the data means, and how to parse it for different types, and uses the sample data as it was intended - a sample. Remy's answer provides the details needed to make the code work with **other data** as well. Yours does not. Read Remy's answer (not just the code). His answer explains how to interpret what you've just decided is `CONST_SIGN` and uses that (non-constant) data to detect what type of image it is, find the appropriate TGraphicsClass, instantiate the proper type, and load the data correctly no matter what type image it is as long as it's a supported type.

Comment: So, to be clear: Remy wrote an actual answer that is useful in future situations. You wrote a hard-coded hack around a single image chunk that is good only in this single instance. Remy's answer shows that your `CONST_SIGN` is not a constant, but a block of data that describes what type of image is in the rest of the block.

Comment: Zam, thank you for the answer! 
I accepted the Remy's answer because of the explanation of the points. 
But anyway your answer was useful!

Answer (score 0):

I had cause to do this recently, later version of Delphi (not sure what version it was introduced) has the LoadFromStream function so the functions I created are as follows.

```
Function ImageToHex(Image:Timage; LineLen:integer):Tstringlist;
var ms:TmemoryStream; s:String; t:Ansistring;
begin
  ms:=tmemorystream.Create;
  try
    image.Picture.SaveToStream(ms);
    setlength(t,ms.Size*2);
    BinToHex(ms.Memory^,Pansichar(t),ms.Size);
    Result:=Tstringlist.create;
    repeat
      s:=copy(t,1,LineLen);
      Result.Add(s);
      delete(t,1,LineLen);
    until t='';
  finally
    ms.free
  end;
end;

procedure HexToImage(HexData:TstringList; var Image:Timage);
var ms:TmemoryStream; s:String;
begin
  ms:=TmemoryStream.Create;
  s:=HexData.Text;
  try
    ms.Size := Length(s) div 2;
    HexToBin(PChar(s), ms.Memory^, ms.Size);
    Image.Picture.LoadFromStream(ms);
  finally
    ms.free
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked @remy-lebeau explanation, but once one knows that the PNG image is well preserved in the hex data, it was straightforward to save the .dfm file subset  posted above into so2.dfm and use the following perl one-liner to convert it to binary.

perl -ne 'END{$PNG=index $b,"PNG"; die "PNG" if $PNG<1; print substr $b,$PNG-1; } $b.=pack "H*",$1 if ( /object img1:/i ... /}/ ) and (/Picture.Data = {/i ... /}/) and m/^\s*([0-9A-F]+)}?\s*$/ ' so2.dfm  >  img1.png